# Let $X$ be the set of all sequences whose elements lie in $\{0,1\}$. Now consider the metric space $(X,d)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be the set of all sequences whose elements lie in $\{0,1\}$. Now consider the metric space $(X,d)$  with $d(x,y)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i-y_i|2^{-i}$ where $x=(x_i)$ and $y=(y_i)$ lies in $X$. Now define a map $f:X\rightarrow[0,1]$ by $f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_i}{2^i}$ where $x=(x_i)\in X$. Show that $f$ is not an open map.

A map is said to be open if it maps open sets to open sets.

Please given some idea. I know that $f$ is bounded, onto and continuous

Comment: Let $x = (0,1,0,0,0,\dotsc)$. When $d(x,y) < 2^{-4}$, what can you say about the relation between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$?

Comment: I think there is no relation

Answer (score 1):

Take for example
$$
x=(0,1,0,0,0,\ldots),
\qquad
\text{then}
\qquad
f(x)=\frac{1}{4}.
$$
If $B(x,1/8)=\{y\in X: d(x,y)<1/8\}$, then $B(x,1/8)$ is open, and if
$y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots)\in B(x,1/8)$,
then $y_1=0$ and $y_2=1$. Hence
$$
\frac{1}{4}\in f\big(B(x,1/8)\big)
\quad\text{and}\quad f\big(B(x,1/8)\big)\subset [¼,1],
$$
which means that $f\big(B(x,1/8)\big)$ can not be open.

Comment: How we can conclude that  $y_1=0,y_2=1$ and $f\big(B(x,1/8)\big)\subset [¼,1]$

Comment: Because if $y_1=1$ or $y_2=$, then $d(x,y)\ge 1/4$ and hence $y\not\in B(x,1/8)$.

Comment: ok. Would you please ecplain how we have got $ f\big(B(x,1/8)\big)\subset [¼,1]$

Comment: how can you say that $f\big(B(x,1/8)\big)\subset [¼,1],$ and $f\big(B(x,1/8)\big)$ is not open?

Comment: Is the solution really correct?